# SQL Sum Names and Get How Many Times they occur in the database as a Percentage

Tags: sql

I have a database where I store names every computer make and model when they get booked into our system as ticket.  I want to SUM up the unique values and display a table showing how many the computer manufacturer name appears.

i.e.

```
HP       30%
Dell     10%
Toshiba  40%
Sony     20%
```

My query looks like this which shows every occurrence from every ticket.  I am not sure how to go about translating to the table above:

```
SELECT
  ComputerMake.ComputerMakeName
FROM
  Ticket
  INNER JOIN Asset ON Ticket.AssetID = Asset.AssetID
  INNER JOIN ComputerMake ON Asset.ComputerMakeID = ComputerMake.ComputerMakeID
```

I am sure its a simple job of summing up each ComputerMakeName but this is beyond my basic SQL experience!

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Will you post the schema for these tables

Comment: I started writing this in linq, changed it to SQL.. I will remove the linq tag!

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you need to count how many times each computer make is booked, and then calc the percentage:

```
SELECT
  ComputerMake.ComputerMakeName
 , count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from FROM 
                      Ticket
                      INNER JOIN Asset ON Ticket.AssetID = Asset.AssetID
                      INNER JOIN ComputerMake ON Asset.ComputerMakeID = ComputerMake.ComputerMakeID) as count_computers
FROM 
  Ticket
  INNER JOIN Asset ON Ticket.AssetID = Asset.AssetID
  INNER JOIN ComputerMake ON Asset.ComputerMakeID = ComputerMake.ComputerMakeID
 group by ComputerMake.ComputerMakeName
```

Comment: This is pretty bad. You are using a  correlated sub query `select count(*) from t`.  And a what are you grouping on 1?

Comment: Your new query is probably worse. That `select count(*) ...` will run for ever row in the main queries result set. Its call RBAR, Row By Agonizing Row. So if there are 20 results in the outer query that `select count(*)....` will run 20 times.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I am looking for.

Comment: @gh9 I agree with you that it's not efficient at all.. but given that the person who asked the question didn't give any details about schema, tables, data size etc. , I just wanted to give him/her an idea about how to get it done. If it's slow, they can create views or some other way to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using CTE to simplify the query and avoid redundancy

```
WITH computer_CTE(computerName) AS
(
    SELECT ComputerMake.ComputerMakeName
    FROM Ticket
    INNER JOIN Asset ON Ticket.AssetID = Asset.AssetID
    INNER JOIN ComputerMake ON Asset.ComputerMakeID = ComputerMake.ComputerMakeID
)
Select computerName, (Count(*) * 100 / (Select Count(*) From computer_CTE)) as Percent
From computer_CTE
Group By computerName
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. I also need to include "where Ticket.CreateDate > @StartDate and Ticket.CreateDate < @EndDate" so the percentage can be calculated based on total devices created between the start and end date.  Adding this after the inner join worked great.

Comment: @belliez I'm glad it was useful to you